# Debug a specific test/spec in RubyMine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rubymine

I'm using RubyMine for RoR development, and RSpec as a test framework.

I'm frequently using "Debug spec" configuration for running specs and I find it very useful. But it takes a very long time for all the tests to finish running, especially with the debugger attached to the process.

**How do I debug a specific test/spec in RubyMine?**

Answer (score 3):

1. Do a right mouse click on the individual test you
   want to run (it "xxx" do), or the context/describe description.
2. Select 'Run xxx...'